# How can I change a typo in the author affiliation after publication?

Tags: publications, errors-erratum, affiliation, acm

I am really needing help. There is a typo on my University Name, however  the paper is already published. Is there any way to still change it? The paper has been published on ACM Platform.

I am very concerned about the reputation of my research with this minor typo. I spent a lot of effort to this research and just realize that...

Comment: Have you contacted the editor yet?

Comment: Not yet, I was concercing because I just read it: " 2.6 Fixity of Works

ACM does not alter works once published. There are times, however, when it is appropriate to publish a revised or corrected version of a work; doing so requires the approval of the responsible editor." Do you think that there is any solution for that?

Comment: You can send an erratum, but I don't think is so important. Either way, it is  not an important problem.

Comment: I edited your post before to correct a language error ("concercing a lot" is not valid English) and to remove the "thanks" because on Stack Exchange sites there is a policy of *not* including greetings, signatures, thanks, etc in posts. Not sure why you undid these edits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, *calm down*. This is not as big of a mistake as you think it is. Many if not most published work contains insignificant mistakes such as minor typos. If it would make you feel better, I once had a typo in my own name (I blame autocorrection).

Contact the editor. They are probably going to publish a correction or erratum. If it is already published, they probably won't fix the original published article even if it is online only. (I am not familiar with the ACM Platform.)

Answer (score 6):

Probably you cannot change it , usually journals inform authors to double check names and affiliation when they send galley proof because after publication it's difficult to change them , but the best approach is contacting editor in chief for explaining the mistake , maybe they fix it